# Android Doze: will it affect entire application or its processes separately?

Tags: android, android-service, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-doze, foreground-service

I need to collect GPS data, save it to database and then send it to backend every minute. 
And I just want to make sure that Doze mode will not screw things up.

1. Let's assume that I launch my foreground service and implement `onLocationChanged` callback there.

   Do I have to do all that (collecting/storing/sending) in a foreground service just to be sure that Doze will allow to use GPS / internet?
2. If I want to store/send data somewhere else, e.g. in a `BroadcastReceiver`, how can I be sure that my `BroadcastReceiver` is ready to handle data and is not asleep?
3. There's a bug in Android M, which makes foreground services affected by Doze mode: 
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/37869501/3210556

   A possible woakaround is to launch foreground service in a separate process.

   Assuming there's a foreground service in the app, what exactly is unaffected by doze?

   - The foreground service itself?
   - The process associated with the foreground service?
   - The whole app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone goes into `Doze`everything gets put to sleep (GPS,Alarms,Internet etc) And gets deferred to a maintenance window at some point (Depending on what version of android the user has).

If your app needs to do something at a specific time you you can request to [white list](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#support_for_other_use_cases) your app. You can review the valid use cases for white listing [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#whitelisting-cases) which sounds like your case could be valid

Comment: Foreground service is supposed to bring the app out of doze mode. The question is asking if the separate process is considered foreground or the whole app is.